# Difference in filter() usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter

I have found that `filter(function, iterable)` no more returns list, but iterable filter object (for Python 3). And it has to be converted to list like this: `list(filter(find_first, groups))`. Also I'm expecting that arguments are evaluated first, before pass to function.

I have found odd behaviour of `filter()` which I don't understand:

```
# scale_groups is of type list
res = filter(find_first, scale_groups)
first = list(res)
res2 = list(filter(find_first, scale_groups))
```

I'm expecting `first` and `res2` to contain the same elements, but `first` is **empty list**, `res2` contains expected **one element**.

```
def get_first_scale_group_by_name(self, name):
    scale_groups = self.as_client.describe_auto_scaling_groups()['AutoScalingGroups']

    def find_first(group):
        return group['AutoScalingGroupName'].startswith(name)
    res = filter(find_first, scale_groups)
    res2 = list(filter(find_first, scale_groups))
    first = list(res)
    return first
```

Comment: you aren't using filter right. the 'name' in the find_first method could change arbitrarily at runtime causing issues.also you should change it to include some data we check so we can replicate it ourselves

Comment: Why it is not right? This is closure which will use name which is linked at time of call `find_first`. This outer name variable will be taken as name parameter of `get_first_scale_group_by_name`. And this parameter can't be changed arbitraly, isn't it?

Comment: well more that it's a bad way to do it as someone who wasn't aware of it could accidentally break your code because it isn't obviously related.

Comment: I could not reproduce your results when using your code and some dummy values for `scale_groups`. Are you sure there is nothing else going on? Any chance you might have a self-contained example that exhibits the strange `filter` behavior?